# convert df to list of list

Tags: python, pandas

How to get the following output of list of lists from the dataframe:

Input dataframe:

```
     0          1
0   if         IN
1   trade      NN   
2   figures    NNS
3   for        IN
4   September  NNP
5   ,          ,
6   due        JJ   
7   for        IN
8   release    NN
9   tomorrow   NN
10  ,          ,
```

Output list:

```
[[('if', 'IN'),
 ('trade', 'NN'),
 ('figures', 'NNS'),
 ('for', 'IN'),
 ('September', 'NNP'),
 (',', ',')],
 [('due', 'JJ'),
 ('for', 'IN'),
 ('release', 'NN'),
 ('tommorow', 'NN'),
 (',', ',')]]
```

The list splits whenever there is delimiter `,`

Comment: The inner list contains pair of the 1st and 2nd column

Answer (score 1):

**Modified answer** : based on the comment about splitting once there is a delimiter of `',', ','`:

```
outputList = list([[]])
ind = 0
for value in df.values:
    value = tuple(value)
    outputList[ind].append(value)
    if (value == (',', ',')):
        outputList.append(list([]))
        ind += 1

#remove last empty inner list which is empty    
outputList.pop()
```

**The output:**

```
[[('if', 'IN'), ('trade', 'NN'), ('figures', 'NNS'), ('for', 'IN'), ('September', 'NNP'), (',', ',')], [('due', 'JJ'), ('for', 'IN'), ('release', 'NN'), ('tomorrow', 'NN'), (',', ',')]]
```

**First answer**:

In order to convert dataframe to array of tuples, you can:

```
outputList = [[tuple(value) for value in df.values]]
outputList
```

**The output:**

```
[[('if', 'IN'), ('trade', 'NN'), ('figures', 'NNS'), ('for', 'IN'), ('September', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('due', 'JJ'), ('for', 'IN'), ('release', 'NN'), ('tomorrow', 'NN'), (',', ',')]]
```

Comment: The outer list contains several inner lists which are split whenever there is any delimiter like ,  as shown at row 6

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
g = df.isin([',', '.']).any(axis=1).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()

L = df.groupby(g).apply(lambda x: [tuple(x) for x in x.to_numpy()]).tolist()
print (L)
[[('if', 'IN'), ('trade', 'NN'), ('figures', 'NNS'), ('for', 'IN'), ('September', 'NNP'), (',', ',')], 
 [('due', 'JJ'), ('for', 'IN'), ('release', 'NN'), ('tomorrow', 'NN'), (',', ',')]]
```

Comment: The outer list contains several inner lists which are split whenever there is any delimiter like , or .